# How to get my Daemon run first

Tags: macos

I have my com.appname.file.plist with the Key RunAtLoad YES, but I need that this Daemon run before the user can open Safari or any other Web Browser, there is a way to make it start first??

Comment: Did you ever find a way to resolve this?

Comment: No, in fact I wont work in this project ever again. But if you find it let me know.

Answer (score 1):

use `launchd`. Place your plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons. Take a look at [Technical Note TN2083 Daemons and Agents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html)

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.appname.file.plist
```

Comment: I´ve done that, but it takes a minute to start de application, and I want it to start first, not after a minute.

Comment: are you checking for GUI session in main function or something else ?

Answer (score -1):

I just add the key "Nice". This optional key specifies what [nice(3)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/nice.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/nice) value should be applied to the daemon. The priority is a value in the range -20 to 20.  The default priority is 0; lower priorities cause more favorable scheduling.

Comment: nice just sets the CPU priority by running so takes a larger proportion on CPU - it does not make a daemon run earlier